# How to understand the minimum operating time of motor drive?

Tags: pwm, motor-controller, motordriver, dead-time

When researching PWM control of brushed motors, I noticed that the motor drive data sheets usually have the following time descriptions.

[image]

[image]

```
Ton：output enable time 
Toff：output disable time 
Trise(or Td(on)):IN high to OUT high 
Tfall(of Td(off)):IN low to OUT low
Some data sheets also use Tpd to describe Trise and Tfall(I'm not sure if this is correct) 
Tdead: output dead time.
```

I have two questions here:

1. I want to get the minimum working time of a motor drive, can it be simply understood as the following formula?
   Twork = Ton+Tdead+Trise(/Tpd)+Toff+Tdead+Tfall(/Tpd)
2. Does the square wave duration of PWM pulses have to be greater than Twork?
   But if Tsw <Twork, what kind of influence will the motor drive cause?

Comment: please edit your question, add a link to the datasheet

Comment: mp6513
https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/documentview/productdocument/index/version/2/document_type/Datasheet/lang/en/sku/MP6513GJ-Z/document_id/169/

DRV8220
https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8220.pdf?ts=1711584673148&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fsitesearch%252Fko-kr%252Fdocs%252Funiversalsearch.tsp%253FlangPref%253Dko-KR%2526searchTerm%253DDRV8220%2526nr%253D86

Comment: add the links to the question ... a comment is not the place for it